# Django 1.5, media root issue

Tags: django, media, root

'm having some trouble setting my media root in Django 1.5
This is the structure of my project

```
./Project
   /Project
   /blog
   /users
   /forum
   /media
        /css
        /img
        /js
   /manage.py
```

But the program can't find css and images. I changed settings.py in multiple ways, but i can't find a solution. Attual settings are:

```
PROJECT_PATH = os.path.abspath(os.curdir).replace('\\', '/')
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.realpath(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, 'media')))
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.realpath(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, 'static')))
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably following code will work for you, add it this code into the urls.py file

```
#return admin static files from same server
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += patterns('django.contrib.staticfiles.views',
        url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'serve'),
    )
```

In settings.py add following line (I think for this you need to comment `# STATIC_ROOT = 'static'`)

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),)
```

Edit:

```
url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 
   'django.views.static.serve', { 'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT, }),
```

Comment: what it gives you when you accessing the static files via url??

Comment: @user3803558 check I have updated the ans.  also please let me know, what you get when u access the static url?

Comment: ok i found the solution, i had to put

     url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {
            'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT,
        }), 

in the urls.py file into the main directory

Comment: @user3803558 ok. I just updated the answer. it will help some one else.. just want to know that.. was you tried adding `media` in the mentioned line `url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$'`